# Getting an error code in Unity for UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, apk, unity3d-gui

I am getting an error code and don't know how to resolve it.  I can build a game in Unity3D and create an APK file for Android, but as the file is finishing up the build the following error code.

---

Could not extract GUID in text file projectsettings/projectsettings.asset at line 44.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

---

Does anyone have a solution to this code and why the GUID could not be extracted?

The issue that I am facing is there is no warnings and no error other codes.  My game plays fine in the editor and can execute on command with the .exe file, however, the .apk file that is transferred to my Android device crashes on load.  I don't know if the error code for the GUID extraction is causing the .apk file to not execute on my Android device.

Also, I am using a Texture Compression of ETC for all of my PNG files to make the file considerably lower on size than with the original file size so the game will not overload my Android device.

The game's apk file is 69.94 MB after the build.

Comment: When you double click on the error, does it show you a script?

Comment: The error seems to be an internal error from Unity3D editor and has nothing to do with your issue. Try delete the file projectsettings/projectsettings.asset and reopen Unity3D to fix the damaged file. Note the project settings of your project may lost after doing this.

Comment: You need to connect your phone to the computer and open device log(on Visual Studo, at menu Tools/Android/Device Log) to see what error occurs when it crashes.

Comment: I'm getting this err on 5.6.3 when I build on WINDOWS, is the thing. It isn't specific to Android. I haven't resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS THE SOLUTION

So the issue (at least on my side) as people mentioned above is coming from having `splashScreenBackgroundSourceLandscape` and `splashScreenBackgroundSourcePortrait` set to `{fileID: 0, guid: 000000000000000000000000000000000, type: 0}`. First confirm that you also have the same issue for the same fields. If not just look at your error message and find which field is giving you this error it should have that trail of zeros as the ID.
Now just search for `m_SplashScreenBackgroundLandscape`, `m_SplashScreenBackgroundPortrait` or just add `m_` in front of the field name that has this problem and search for it in the file. You should be able to find the correct value there, just copy and paste the value in those fields that have the problem. For example for me the correct value for `splashScreenBackgroundSourceLandscape` should have been {fileID: 21300000, guid: 2ae2e71466b7e4132a2f6e5828f57fa6, type: 3}. This should solve the issue.

Plan B

Go ahead and find the GUID of the file that is set for splash screen. You can find it in its corresponding `.meta` file. So if the file name is `splashscreen.png` you should look for `splashscreen.png.meta`. Search for that GUID in your entire project, if you are using text based YAML format for all your assets then you should be able to find a reference to that file in some other place. After you find it just copy the value which should look like the value above and paste it where the problem is coming from.

Hope it helps you all, let me know if you encounter any other issues.